# center a specific set of node

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the command to force center a set of nodes on the page ? I'm trying to design a diagram with a center axis but adding nodes next to it will result in a decentered axis.

[image: here I want the red part to be centered]

here I want the red part to be centered

here is the code :

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(engrenage)[contour]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    %engrenage
    \node (cran1) [engrenage] {};
    \node (cran2) [engrenage, below of=cran1]{};
    \node (cran3) [engrenage, below of=cran2]{};
    \node (cran4) [engrenage, below of=cran3]{};
    \node (cran5) [engrenage, below of=cran4]{};
    \node (cran6) [engrenage, below of=cran5]{};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
};

%cran
\node (cran_gauche) [cran, below of=cran3, xshift = -2cm, yshift = 10.15cm]{};
\node (cran_droit) [cran, below of =cran_gauche, xshift = 4cm, yshift = -0.8cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{position repos}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is incomplete. Even worse, it nests `tikzpictures`. Please add a code that starts with `\documentclass` and can be compiled. I'd think that your problems could get solved if you avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing a `\centering` command supposing that you figure was symmetric.

In any case here you have another way of drawing something similar but avoiding nested `tikzpictures`. Main differences are the use of `positioning`, `backgrounds` and `fit` libraries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning, backgrounds}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    contour/.style={fill=red!30, draw, rounded corners},
    engrenage/.style={draw, fill=red!60, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=5mm, rounded corners},
    cran/.style={draw, fill=blue!30, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=5mm, rounded corners},
    node distance=2cm
]

    \node (cran1) [engrenage] {};
    \node (cran2) [engrenage, below = of cran1]{};
    \node (cran3) [engrenage, below = of cran2]{};
    \node (cran4) [engrenage, below = of cran3]{};
    \node (cran5) [engrenage, below = of cran4]{};
    \node (cran6) [engrenage, below = of cran5]{};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node(engrenage)[contour, fit=(cran1) (cran6)] {};
    \end{scope}

%cran
\node (cran_gauche) [cran, below left = 0 and -2mm of cran3.south]{};
\node (cran_droit) [cran, above right = 0 and -2mm of cran4.north]{};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{position repos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]